# Corova geolocation plugin: Use geolocation only when using the app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ngcordova

Xcode shows me two privacy settings:

> Privacy - Location Always Usage Description

and

> Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

I don't need always the user location. Is there a way to disable the first usage description with the plugin?

I use the plugin with this code:

```
$cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function(pos) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(49.890224, 20.475327));
        var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
          map: map,
          icon: "img/pos.png",
          title: "My Location"
        });


      }, function(err) {
        // error
      });
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10 , you must specifies the reason for your app to access the user's location information or others user private data.

To do so you need to update your info.plist (please see the image) via Xcode or directly via cordova/ionic [how to add specific configuration parameters to iOS info.plist](http://geeklearning.io/how-to-add-specific-configuration-parameters-to-ios-p-list-and-android-manifest/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so is it possible to just remove the Privacy - Location Always Usage Description or do I have to change my code, so that is is not needed? When I build the app, the plist is automatically updated, so i think it should be changed somewhere in the plugins settings?

Comment: are you using background geolocation or something that require continuous geolocation information? if yes you need to change your code. for the plist you can try , the link technique regards

Comment: no, not at all. The only geolocation based code is the one i've posted in the question.